# Wordpress pages in backend, list with filtered meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying something out with Wordpress. I want to use `page` as a shell for custom content, so I've setup an action that adds a specific `meta_key` for each regular page, so that I can single out the regular pages from my 'special-pages'.

```
function addMetaToPage($post_id) {
  if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

  if(get_post_type($post_id) == 'page') {
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_page', 1, true);
  }
}

if(is_admin()) {
  add_action('save_post', 'addMetaToPage');
}
```

Then, in the admin backend where pages are listed I run this hook to prevent all my 'special-pages' to show up.

```
if(is_admin()) {
  add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    $query->set('meta_key', '_regular_page');
    $query->set('meta_value', 1);
  });
}
```

And it works. Only pages with meta `_regular_page` === `1` shows up. However, the counter just above the table that usually sais something like `All (15)` shows the total number of pages, even though only a couple of them are in the list. [Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSB9J.jpg). At this page I got 4 regular pages and 6 pages that dosn't have the `_regular_page` meta key.

Is there a way to actually fix this? I really thought that the counter was dependent on the WP_Query, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the count of `ALL, Published` and `trash` for the page section in the admin using the filter `views_edit-page`
 you can use something like this

```
 add_filter( "views_edit-page", "filter_regular_page_count", 10, 1); 

 function filter_regular_page_count( $views ) {
     $regular_post_count = 5 ;// you can sort out how to get your regular post count

        $views["all"] = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=page" class="current">All <span class="count">('.$regular_post_count.')</span></a>';
```

//same for published and trash
            return $views;
     }

here is example of var dump of views

```
array (size=3)
  'all' => string '<a href='edit.php?post_type=page' class="current">All <span class="count">(7)</span></a>' (length=88)
  'publish' => string '<a href='edit.php?post_status=publish&amp;post_type=page'>Published <span class="count">(7)</span></a>' (length=102)
  'trash' => string '<a href='edit.php?post_status=trash&amp;post_type=page'>Trash <span class="count">(2)</span></a>' (length=96)
```

if you want to do the same thing for the posts, WordPress use `views_edit-post` filter for the posts

actually wordpress use something like this as the filter of the views section ---> `views_{$this->screen->id}`